# Let $f$ be periodic function with fundamental period $\tau$. Prove that function $f(nx)$ have fundamental period $\frac{\tau}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be periodic function with fundamental period $\tau$, prove that function $f(nx)$ have fundamental period $\frac{\tau}{n}$.

My idea:

 First I need to show that $\frac{\tau}{n}$ is a period.
$$f(n(x+\frac{\tau}{n}))= f(nx + \tau) = f(nx).$$
But how to show that this is the smallest such?
Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x) = f(nx)$. You have shown that if $f$ has a period $\tau$ then $g$ has period ${\tau \over n}$.

The same reasoning shows that if $g$ has period $T$ then $f$ has period $nT$.

If $\tau$ is a **fundamental** period of $f$ then any $T$ period of $g$ must therefore
satisfy $nT \ge \tau$, or in other words, $T \ge { \tau \over n}$. Hence $ { \tau \over n}$ is a fundamental period of $g$.

Comment: Why this period of g must therefore satisfy nT≥τ ?

Comment: If $T$ is a period of $g$ then $nT$ is a period of $f$. Since $\tau$ is the fundamental period of $f$ we must have $nT \ge \tau$ otherwise this would contradict $\tau$ being the fundamental period of $f$.